# Sending single PDF attachment in a visualforce email template

Tags: visualforce-component

I'm trying to send single PDF attachment in a Visualforce email template being used in an approval process.
**Custom Component -**

```
<apex:component controller="findExpenseLines" access="Global">
  <apex:attribute name="expense_report" type="Id" assignTo="{!reportId}" description="Id of the expense report"/>
      <table border = "2" cellspacing = "5">
            <tr>
                <td>Expense Item Number</td>
                <td>Expense Item Date</td> 
                <td>Source Location</td>   
                <td>Destination Location</td>
                <td>Kms Travelled</td>
                <td>Expense Incurred</td>             
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!expenseItems}" var="item">
            <tr>
                <td>{!item.Name}</td>
                <td>{!item.AppointDate__c}</td>
                <td>{!item.Source__c}</td>
                <td>{!item.Destination__c}</td>
                <td>{!item.Kms_Travelled__c}</td>
                <td>{!item.Expense_Incurred__c}</td>              
            </tr>
            </apex:repeat>        
     </table>
    </apex:component>
```

When I try to compile the below **Visualforce Email Template -** it throws an error -

> Error: Component  definition does not contain
>   apex:componentBody> so it cannot be used with any child tags.

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Expense Report Approval for User: {!relatedTo.Owner.Name}" recipientType="User" relatedToType="Expense_Report__c">
<messaging:htmlEmailBody >
<html>
        <body>
            <p>Dear {!recipient.Manager.Name}</p>
            <p>{!relatedTo.Owner.Name} has raised an Expense Approval request for the period between {!relatedTo.Period_Start_Date__c} and {!relatedTo.Period_End_Date__c} </p>
            <p>The total expense amount for approval is {!relatedTo.Amount__c} </p>
            <p>Please find the below expense line item details for your reference -- </p>
            <c:ExpenseComponent expense_report="{!relatedTo.id}"> 
            </c:ExpenseComponent>
            <br/><br/>
            We look forward to your approval action
            <br/><br/>
            Best,
            <br/><br/>
            CRM Admin            
        </body>
</html>
</messaging:htmlEmailBody>

<messaging:attachment filename="ExpenseReport.pdf" renderAs="PDF">
       <c:ExpenseComponent expense_report="{!relatedTo.id}">></c:ExpenseComponent> 
    </messaging:attachment>
</messaging:emailTemplate>
```

I understand that apex:componentBody is to be used inside my custom component but it is breaking  the whole formation of email template. I am unable to grasp the significance of tag apex:componentBody>, please provide your valuable views

Comment: Is the component used to create the Expense Report? If so, that's what your code is expecting you to try and do again by including the component in your email template. I don't think you want to include it in your template based on what I can see of the component which creates tables. Are you wanting to create tables in your email? If not, remove the component.

Comment: @crmprogdev I have also tried removing the component(creating table) from the email template i.e. removing it from </messaging:htmlEmailBody> tag and placed the component inside <messaging:attachment tag. I face a different error - "Error: Component <c:expensecomponent> definition does not contain <apex:componentBody> so it cannot be used with any child tags." In a nutshell I have to use  <apex:componentBody> inside my component if want to use <messaging:attachmen> tag inside my template. I'm facing issues with how to use <apex:componentBody> this tag breaks the formation

Comment: why are you forcing VF to use componentBody? This occurs because you are using `<c:ExpenseComponent ...></c:ExpenseComponent>` construction rather than `<c:ExpenseComponent ... />`  It doesn't look like your application requires it - see https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_componentBody.htm?search_text=componentBody

Comment: @crop1645 using `<c:ExpenseComponent ... />` cuts my component to half. I can see the only table headers. The `<apex:repeat` construction is not rendered

Comment: Perhaps I'm confused here. You mention a PDF. Are you trying to render your email template as a PDF or are you trying to attach what the component renders as a PDF? If the latter, I think you may want to take a different approach to what you're trying to accomplish. Render the report, then attach it to an email template that doesn't reference the details of the data within it. It appears as though you may be trying to do both. I don't believe you can't send an email template that renders one or more of it's pages as a PDF, but you can attach a PDF to the email the template creates.

Comment: @crmprogdev I am trying to render the component as PDF and attach it to the email template. This prompts me to use {<c:ComponentBody>} tag, but this tag breaks the formation of my custom component.

Comment: Bennie -- does the component controller actually return a list of expenses items in the getter for `{!expenseItems}`?  The custom controller will only know about the value `{!reportId}` assigned immediately after the custom component controller is constructed.

Comment: If you're trying to render the component as a PDF, then you don't want it in your email template. You want to do something like getContentAsPDF or use a controller to assemble/attach the PDF to an email *after* the PDF has been rendered. I don't think you can do it all at once from a template. Someone will correct me if I'm mistaken. If you can do that, it would be new functionality that I'm not up to date on. You might be able to `getContentAsPDF` or similar to obtain the attachment but not as part of the template.

Comment: @crop1645 I understand that controller will know `{!reportId}` only after it's constructed. The component on email template works fine as the component controller returns the list of expense items. The whole thing breaks when I introduce `{<messaging:attachment}` tag and put my custom component inside this tag. I wonder why!

Comment: @crmprogdev Hi Cal, As advised by you I'll develop a new apex page so that I can call `getContentAsPDF` on it.  As I need this PDF along with the approval process emails, I may run into complexity as `getContentAsPDF` is not supported in triggers so a future call may help (approval action field update will call this trigger). But I read [here](http://cloudwharf.com/blog/category/app-development/apex-visualforce/) that future method returns blank PDF. So I have to develop a REST service and do a self-call

Comment: Yes, I think @future support has been delayed twice now for `getContentAsPDF`. I think it's now scheduled for SP16 which isn't far away if you can wait. Might want to try a beta org DevOrg to see if its GA. Such a hassle to need to do a REST service for this. Glad you understand now what you need to do though. Make certain your page prints correctly when rendered as PDF or that call won't work regardless. Same restrictions apply as to normal renderAsPDF pages.

Comment: @crmprogdev hi Cal, After Winter 16 release(21 Oct 2015), we do not even need an self-call to REST API. Because getContent() and getContentAsPdf() both are now allowed in Asynch apex. This means we can use getContentAsPdf() in future or Queueable interface. I quickly tried it on my sandbox and it's generating the pdf like a charm.

Comment: Make certain your Dev Org isn't a Spring 16 preview org. According to the [W16 Release notes](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_vf_pagereference_getcontent_cruc.htm) the Async portion was delayed to SP16. I remember seeing parts of it come up for Critical Update Activation in some orgs despite those notes, but I'd double check it in a production org to be safe.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for the word of caution. I'll double check.